# how to activate swap

Tags: swap

I have a 16gb card in my laptop running Lubuntu 18.04, which is formatted as swap. when I click on activate partition in Disks I get this error:

[image: screenshot]

while the partition is recognized as swap by the app

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Did you ever run mkswap on that partition?

Comment: do I do     `mkswap /dev/sdb1`

Comment: That should use the whole partition, see the man page, man mkswap.

Comment: if you know what should be done pls show it, otherwise you should not post anything.

Comment: What you wrote is exactly the command, so "Yes" to your question.

Comment: I get an error:  `sudo mkswap /dev/sdb1
    [sudo] password for stephen: 
    mkswap: cannot open /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy`

Comment: if smb can provide instruction how to do this in gparted, please do.